# Handle flash button using WatiN

Tags: c#, flash, automated-tests, watin

I am using WatiN for browser automation. Its cool. But today i ended up in a problem where i need to call the flash object (uploadify button) in my asp.net page.

This code seems working fine, but doesn't show any actions

```
        Element ele = window.Element(Find.ById("uploadifyUploader"));
        ele.Click();
```

Is there a way to achive this in WatiN.?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think that firing `ele.Click()` results in clicking on `<object/>` element, but not the button. The content of the `<object/>` element is just an application. You have flash object there, but it could be, for example, Java applet.

Clicking on that button is similar to clicking button on different application - you have to automate Windows, not IE, so some kind of API calls will be needed, like `FindWindowEx` or `SendMessage` etc. I think that using `WatiN.Core.Native.Windows` namespace could be a little bit helpful, but probably insufficient. You will have to use some extern methods from `user32.dll`.

Instead of this, you could use some kind of library for Windows automation. I heard that [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) is good, but I didn't use it. For small tasks I prefer to deal with native calls.

Additionally, [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) is very helpful for finding windows properties.

Comment: yeah thats what i thought initially, native win32 calls would be better. Actuallly i have tried mouse_event in user32.dll to click the button. But nothing seems to work. I dont know whats the problem.. :(